# Powershell script in Visual Studio 2010 Post-Build Step

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, post-build-event

I have a powershell script that works wonderfully from the powershell shell and from a cmd window, and now I am trying to launch it from a post-build step in Visual Studio.

After several different variations of trying to get this to lunch and run successfully, I currently have the following configuration for the "Command Line" property of the "Post-Build Event" in VS2010.

This is all on one line in the Post-Build configuration, but I've wrapped the text here just for readability:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive
-File "$(SolutionDir)testScript.ps1"
-ConfigurationFile "$(SolutionDir)configuration.txt"
-SolutionDir "$(SolutionDir)"
-Platform "$(Platform)"
-Configuration "$(Configuration)"
```

The powershell script expects 4 mandatory parameters: ConfigurationFile, SolutionDir, Platform, and Configuration.  As you can see, I am providing each of those parameters above, and am enclosing them in double quotes to protect against spaces in the values.

In VS2010, the SolutionDir macro expands to a path that has spaces, Platform expands to "Release", and Configuration expands to "Win32".

When the post-build step executes, this is the error I get:

```
testScript.ps1 : Cannot process command because of one or more missing
mandatory parameters: Platform Configuration.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [testScript.ps1], 
    ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameter,testScript.ps1
```

...any ideas what I could be missing?  It is apparently able to find the script in $(SolutionDir), but I can't tell whether it's picking up any of the command line arguments.  Could the trailing '\' character in $(SolutionDir) be hanging this up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The variable `$(SolutionDir)`, since it is a directory ends in a backslash '\'. So, when the variable is expanded, the argument for `-SolutionDir "$(SolutionDir)"` looks like this:

```
-SolutionDir "c:\Your Solution Dir\"
```

when this is parsed the final slash effectively escapes the closing quote and the shell parser does not see the end of the argument, so the parameter to `-SolutionDir` "sucks in" the rest of the arguments into the SolutionDir argument. You can fix this by escaping the final backslash with another one by adding a trailing slash:

> -SolutionDir "$(SolutionDir)\"

Comment: Sure as shootin' that was it.  Thanks!

Comment: I have had lots of trouble passing in directories to Powershell in the past without knowing why (I was seeing quirky behavior like this), and this explains it perfectly. **THANK YOU!**